# Persist my cron jobs and execute them even if my node server restarted

Tags: node.js, cron, cron-task

I have my app in **node js**
and i want them to be executed on its scheduled time
But the problem is in between that **if my server crash/stop/restart then those scheduled jobs are not persisted and are not executed.**
Also, all my jobs are scheduled and executed using only single process, but i want multiple process to do the job.
I want all my jobs to be **persisted and executed even if my node server restarted** or better its get executed even if my server is not running.
**Agenda** - using mongoDB, which i don't want to use.
**Node**-scheduler - not able to persist cron jobs

```
    var ctab = require('crontab');
    ctab.load(function(err, crontab) {
      var job = crontab.create('* * * * * *');
      var jobs = crontab.jobs();
      crontab.save(function(err, crontab) {
    });
});
```

Comment: If you don't add some code and more information, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I'am searching for a node package which can persist cron jobs and can be executed even if my system restarted
what happens now is all scheduled jobs are gone once i restart my server.

Comment: @ShubhamTripathi, why can't you use Agenda ? did you try that ? I also need something like this, i think agenda should be the right choice.

Comment: Daga - will agenda work in case my server got restarted as node is a single threaded and what happen if my server stops at the time of job execution, will that job executed even if my server is not running

Answer (score 8):

There is a few node packages to management and persist scheduled jobs:

- [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) (mongodb persistence)
- [Bree](https://github.com/breejs/bree) (Redis persistence)
- [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) (Redis persistence)
- [nodejs-persistable-scheduler](https://github.com/easyfan/nodejs-persistable-scheduler) (MySql persistence)